# El archivo ejecutable de depuracion no existe

Tags: c#, visual-studio

estoy intentando ejecutar un programa sencillo en visual studio, pero cuando intento ejecutarlo, me sale el siguiente error: "El archivo ejecutable de depuración 'C:...Ejecutable.exe' no existe."

También me sale un error en el que el archivo .dll no existe.

CONTEXTO: Ejecutable es mi proyecto donde tengo el main.
Librería es el proyecto donde guardo todos los métodos, el cual está referenciado a Ejecutable.

He intentado borrarlo, crearlo de nuevo, quitar y poner referencias y ya no se que mas hacer.
Espero una respuesta, muchas gracias